# Spark job yarn error exit code: 11

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, pyspark

That said, I've come up empty handed on this error.  We are new to spark, hadoop and yarn, but haven't been able to find anything around an error we're seeing in a job we're trying to launch.  See the error below.

**This is an intermittent issue we are seeing.  We can kick off the job once and it works fine, next iteration we have to start it 3 times to get it to run.  Have tried waiting from 1s to 1 day between runs, no difference.

> > 2015-12-22 11:37:57,163 WARN  nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor (DefaultContainerExecutor.java:launchContainer(223)) - Exit code from
> >     container container_e15_1449773992897_0324_01_000001 is : 11
> >     2015-12-22 11:37:57,163 WARN  nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor
> >     (DefaultContainerExecutor.java:launchContainer(229)) - Exception from
> >     container-launch with container ID:
> >     container_e15_1449773992897_0324_01_000001 and exit code: 11
> >     ExitCodeException exitCode=11:
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:576)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:487)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:753)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
> >             at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Where we are:

- Pyspark job in 10 node Hortonworks based hadoop/spark cluster (2 managers and 8 workers)
- code reads files from HDFS and aggregates the data (error occurs saving both to s3 and back to hdfs
- job submit: spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1 --master yarn-cluster --driver-memory 30G  --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 10 --executor-memory 50G request_test.py arg1 arg2
- spark version 1.4.1, hadoop 2.3.2.
- configurations to sparkcontext:

> conf = conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "8g")   conf =
>   conf.set("spark.akka.frameSize", "1000")   conf =
>   conf.set("spark.shuffle.blockTransferService","nio")   conf =
>   conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
>   conf = conf.set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")   conf =
>   conf.set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "3000")   conf =
>   conf.set("spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead", "3000")

Some of these were later trials to remedy the error

We have isolated the issue to the worker nodes when executing and pulled the error from the logs. Hadoop shows the jobs as Finished with Failed status, spark logs show similar exit code 11. We've been searching and are unable to find anything around the exit code and its meaning. We've been digging through source code to trace the error and will continue.  In the meantime, i'm hoping someone has seen this before and can assist!

**EDIT**
Yet Another Trial
spark-submit --verbose --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1 --master yarn-cluster --driver-memory 12G  --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 8 --executor-memory 25G request_test.py arg1 arg2

> verbose output: Parsed arguments: master                  yarn-cluster
>   deployMode              null   executorMemory          25G
>   executorCores           8   totalExecutorCores      null
>   propertiesFile
>   /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf   driverMemory
>   12G   driverCores             null   driverExtraClassPath    null
>   driverExtraLibraryPath  null   driverExtraJavaOptions 
>   -Dhdp.version=2.3.2.0-2950   supervise               false   queue                   null   numExecutors            8   files                   null
>   pyFiles                 null   archives                null
>   mainClass               null   primaryResource
>   file:/datavol/oozie/data-science/request_test.py   name
>   request_test.py   childArgs               [20151227 MoPub]   jars
>   null   packages                org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1
>   repositories            null   verbose                 true
>
> Spark properties used, including those specified through  --conf and
>   those from the properties file
>   /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf:
>   spark.yarn.queue -> default   spark.history.kerberos.principal -> none
>   spark.driver.memory -> 12G   spark.yarn.max.executor.failures -> 3
>   spark.yarn.historyServer.address -> manager01.local:18080
>   spark.history.ui.port -> 18080   spark.yarn.services ->
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryService
>   spark.history.provider ->
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryProvider
>   spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries -> 10
>   spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms -> 5000
>   spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead -> 384
>   spark.yarn.submit.file.replication -> 3
>   spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -> -Dhdp.version=2.3.2.0-2950
>   spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads -> 25
>   spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead -> 384
>   spark.history.kerberos.keytab -> none   spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions
>   -> -Dhdp.version=2.3.2.0-2950   spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files -> false
>
> System properties: spark.yarn.queue -> default
>   spark.history.kerberos.principal -> none spark.executor.memory -> 25G
>   spark.driver.memory -> 12G spark.yarn.max.executor.failures -> 3
>   spark.yarn.historyServer.address -> manager01.local:18080
>   spark.history.ui.port -> 18080 spark.yarn.services ->
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryService
>   spark.history.provider ->
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryProvider SPARK_SUBMIT
>   -> true spark.submit.pyArchives -> pyspark.zip:py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip spark.app.name -> request_test.py
>   spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries -> 10
>   spark.yarn.submit.file.replication -> 3
>   spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead -> 384
>   spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms -> 5000
>   spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead -> 384
>   spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads -> 25
>   spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -> -Dhdp.version=2.3.2.0-2950
>   spark.history.kerberos.keytab -> none spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions
>   -> -Dhdp.version=2.3.2.0-2950 spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files -> false spark.master -> yarn-cluster

Error from yarn application log corresponding to the same worker/container as the yarn worker error above:

> Container: container_e15_1449773992897_0449_01_000001 on
>   worker04.local_45454
>   =============================================================================== LogType:stderr Log Upload Time:Tue Dec 29 07:54:52 -0500 2015
>   LogLength:6861 Log Contents: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J
>   bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/storage/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/filecache/5753/spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] 15/12/29 07:53:12 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:13 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:14 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:14 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:14 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. 15/12/29 07:53:15 WARN
>   spark.SparkConf: The configuration key
>   'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of
>   Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key
>   'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead. [Stage 0:>
>   (166 + 56) / 20180]15/12/29 07:54:01 ERROR nio.ConnectionManager:
>   Corresponding SendingConnection to
>   ConnectionManagerId(worker02.local,42675) not found 15/12/29 07:54:01
>   ERROR nio.ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to
>   ConnectionManagerId(worker03.local,53260) not found 15/12/29 07:54:01
>   ERROR nio.ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to
>   ConnectionManagerId(worker06.local,55520) not found 15/12/29 07:54:01
>   WARN nio.ConnectionManager: All connections not cleaned up End of
>   LogType:stderr
>
> LogType:stdout Log Upload Time:Tue Dec 29 07:54:52 -0500 2015
>   LogLength:2726 Log Contents: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "request_test.py", line 292, in 
>       reducedOutput.coalesce(numFileOutput).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)   File
>   "/storage/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1449773992897_0449/container_e15_1449773992897_0449_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 1486, in saveAsTextFile   File
>   "/storage/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1449773992897_0449/container_e15_1449773992897_0449_01_000001/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 538, in **call**   File
>   "/storage/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1449773992897_0449/container_e15_1449773992897_0449_01_000001/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 300, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o92.saveAsTextFile. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job cancelled because SparkContext
>   was shut down
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:736)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:735)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:735)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1475)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1410)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1644)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$3.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:559)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(Utils.scala:2308)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(Utils.scala:2278)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Utils.scala:2278)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Utils.scala:2278)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(Utils.scala:2278)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(Utils.scala:2278)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(Utils.scala:2278)
>           at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(Utils.scala:2278)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$6.run(Utils.scala:2260)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
>
> End of LogType:stdout

Comment: What is the configuration of your ec2/emr instances in AWS? You are using very high memory settings while running the jobs.

Comment: To troubleshoot run with same settings in yarn-client mode and let us know the result.. And also your driver node has 30G memory available?

Comment: We're using d2.4xl nodes in ec2. These have 122 gb memory per node. Our managers are small c series machines.. What specifically do you need for the config of the ec2 machines?  We are using high memory allocations based on our data sets (approximately 1-2tb of gzip data per run).  Should we try with much smaller allocations? This is a new cluster and we're rather new and haven't been able to spend much time performance tuning and understanding appropriate levels of mem allocs.  Also tried running in client mode, when we execute there, it typically works, will try again and log results

Comment: updated issue w/more granular info from verbose output of another test.

Comment: Are there any application logs ? you can get these using "yarn logs -applicationId <application id>"

Comment: We reviewed those logs but are not seeing anything standing out to research as we've seen these errors/warnings without the exitcode 11. I will get the logs and see how best i can attach to here.

Comment: posted the log above from the yarn application logs corresponding to the worker/container reporting the exit code 11.

Comment: I came across the same situation recently. I know this is very old thread but its worth debugging. Python is not able to store the container cache details it resets it everytime on all nodes in the cluster except one. the issue is intermittent because there is exactly node on the cluster where it runs perfectly. Although I got different error code 13.
Please paste the container logs If anyone is still facing the issue.
Happy to help.

Comment: Ashish, I don't have any recent logs, but i know I was able to solve it eventually with more memory and smarter performance tuning.  This is a vague error in an old version, we're now using databricks on spark 2.4, definitely worth looking upgrade if you have not.